# Найти в MySQL свободное число?

Tags: php, mysql

title это разные пятизначные числа 00001...

- **title**
- 00001
- 00002
- 00003
- 00005
- .....

Как можно найти первое(наименьшее) т.е 00004 свободное число?

```
$rel = $db->super_query("select title+1 from dle_post a where not exists
(select 1 from dle_post b where b.title=a.title+1) order by title limit 1");
echo $rel;
```

Comment: А что такое "свободное число" ?

Comment: Которого нет в базе

Comment: Если предположить что число 1 всегда есть в БД, то `select title+1 from _post a where not exists(select 1 from _post b where b.title=a.title+1 order by title limit 1` И да, это может быть медленным, рекомендуется запоминать число до которого все есть и начинать проверку с него

Comment: MySQL version? 5.7 or 8.0 ?

Comment: MySQL version 5.7

Comment: @Mike Почему-то у меня пишет Array?

Comment: Видимо потому, что функция возвращает массив колонок, что логично. Так что посмотрите его содержимое